# How to merge chunks of text files in a directory to one or more files?

Tags: shell-script

I have a requirement to merge chunks of text files in a directory to one or more files and then zip the merged file.

For ex: If i have half a million text files in a directory, say A. I want to merge sets of 50,000 files into 1 i.e. I will have 10 merged files each having the content of 50,000 files. Finally, I want to zip each merged file, i.e. there will be totally 10 zip files at the end of this process.

I tried doing this in shell script. I am unable to find a solution.

Can someone let me know the most efficient way to achieve this using a shell script?

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you have just one dir with huge set of files, therefore you need to split filelist into small sets, than to concatenate them , then zip and if necessary to delete small files.

I can suggest only the following way:

```
cd /to/dir/with/many/files/
mkdir ../tmp
find . | split -l 50000 ../tmp/x
for i in ../tmp/x* ; do 
    while read filename ; do
        cat "$filename" >> "${i}.text" ;
        # rm "$filename" # uncomment it only if you need to delete small files
    done <"$i"
    zip "${i}.zip"  "${i}.text"
    # rm "${i}.text" # uncomment it only if you need to delete result file
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions, one where `n` files are added to a single archive and one where all the files are first concatenated and then zipped.

Common steps to both approaches are:

```
# Generate a list of files to be zipped
find . -type f > filelist

# Loop to process n files stepwise
n=50000
fileno=1

for i in $(seq 1 $n $(wc -l < filelist)); do
  # compression code goes here, see below
done
```

#### Zip files individually

```
# automatic name generation
zipfile=$(printf "%04d" $((fileno++)))

# extract lines $i to $i+$n-1 from filelist 
sed -n "$i,$((i+n-1))p" filelist | zip $zipfile -@
```

#### Concatenate and zip

If you wanted to do this with `gzip` (and other compressors) it would be quite simple:

```
zipfile=$(printf "%04d" $((fileno++)))
sed -n "$i,$((i+n-1))p" filelist | xargs cat | gzip > $zipfile.gz
```

As `zip` doesn't support this mode (at least not the one I have), you need a different approach. `zip` supports named pipes (`-FI`) where the file inside the archive gets the name of the named pipe, so doing something like this inside the loop should work:

```
zipfile=$(printf "%04d" $((fileno++)))
mkfifo $zipfile
zip -FI $zipfile $zipfile &
sed -n "$i,$((i+n-1))p" filelist | xargs cat > $zipfile
rm $zipfile
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.filename can have a standard prefix, say 1ei. I want to first merge the sets of 50000 files into one text file and then zip it.

Comment: Thanks for the response..I made some modifications to this script..                                                       for i in $(seq 1 2 10); do sed -n "$i,$((i+2 - 1))p" filelist | xargs cat > $i.kkk | zip $i.zip $i.kkk; done      In this code, I am able to merge the files, but when I try to zip, it is creating issue..

Comment: I would recommend sticking with the `zip fname -@` which will add filenames on stdin to `fname.zip`. I added some better zip filename generation to the answer. Also see [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46093/how-to-create-multiple-zips-from-a-directory-containing-a-million-xml-files/46124) for a similar question.

Comment: Thanks..This program zips 50000 txt files in one zip...But I want to first merge all those 50000 txt files into one txt file and then create a zip for that one txt file...Is it possible to achieve this in a single piped command?

Comment: Ah I thought that was what you wanted to do, I'll add an update with concatenation and zipping.

Comment: Fixed a bug in the named pipe usage.

Comment: Thank you Thor..I was thinking of a different approach like immediately after I merge the files, I can invoke another shell script passing the merged file name as an argument..This script will run in the background and create the zip file..In this way, I can achieve multithreading...what do you think?

Comment: Just stick it in after the `cat`. To your second question, that depends on what you're trying to do, I think you should type it up as a new question, giving a good description of what you're trying to do.