# How to create multiple zips from a directory containing a million xml files?

Tags: shell-script, zip

I have a directory containing million xml files.
I want to create multiple zip files containing n number of xml files. For ex: if n = 10000, then I want to create 100 zip files i.e. each zip file will have only 10000 xml files.

What is the most efficient way to create these zip files? I don't want this process to take more time since I have to repeat this operation for multiple folders having millions of xml files.

Answer (score 1):

This may be usefull :

```
$ zip all.zip *.xml  ## create a big archive.
```

Find the archive's total size:

```
$ ls -lh all.zip
```

Now, split the big archive into small archives, as you need:

```
$ split -b 5M all.zip ## creates 5 MB zips
```

Note: extracting the archives does not work, unless you join them back:

```
cat x* > oldbigzip.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
# Create file list
find . -type f -name '*.xml' > filelist

n=10000
fileno=1

# Loop through list, extracting n names each time
for i in $(seq 1 $n $(wc -l < filelist)); do
  zipfile="zipfile$(printf "%04d" $((fileno++)))"
  sed -n "$i,$((i+n-1))p" filelist | zip $zipfile -@
done
```

Comment: I tried this script. It works fast in local unix drive. But, the same script is too slow in a NFS drive. Is there any way to make it faster in NFS drive?

Comment: This is as fast as it can get, the NFS link is the bottleneck. Run the script on the NFS server or get a faster network link.